# Choir boys inhaling helium

Tags: identify-this-song, choral-music

I recently viewed this video with four choir boys singing what sounds like a medieval church hymn. One inhales helium in order to hit the highest notes.

Regardless of the funny content, I was more interested in the music itself. Even after much research, I am unable to identify it.

Youtube: [Angelic meme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypamXjwr8_w&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Fun fact: Inhaling Helium does NOT change the pitch of your voice, but just the timbre. So if you can't hit the note in air, you can't hit with helium either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it afterall.

it is Miserere Mei, (Allegri),  a setting of Psalm 51 (50) by Italian composer Gregorio Allegri.

One rendition: [Miserere mei, Deus - Allegri - Tenebrae](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3v9unphfi0)

Comment: Thanks for coming back to provide the answer!  Please mark your answer as correct by hitting the green checkmark.  If it is not available now, it should become clickable after 24 hours.